# Beginner Q: Is there a cleaner way to group a list in JS?

Tags: javascript, formatting

I'm looking to highlight some words on a webpage, I've grouped them now, but changed the css and html slightly and this seems to have broken it.

For context, looking to add a list of words in JS which would then apply formatting to those words. I changed the p to a span because I wanted them to be an inline-block, which I don't think is possible as a paragraph; however this has broken it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function hiliter(word, element) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", 'gi'); // g modifier for global and i for case insensitive 
    var repl = '<span class="sketch-highlight">' + word + '</span>';
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);

  }

  function hiliteWords(words, element) {
    words.forEach(word => {
      hiliter(word, element);
    });
  }

  //hiliter('dolor', document.getElementById('dolor'));
  hiliteWords(['creo', 'think',
    'mojado', 'wet'
  ], document.getElementById('subs'));
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 0px white;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.825;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.sketch-highlight {
  position: relative;
}

.sketch-highlight::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0em;
  top: 0em;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: darkblue;
  position: absolute;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

.sketch-highlight::after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0em;
  top: 0em;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: darkblue;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Brush+Script&family=Nanum+Pen+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body id='subs'>

    <center>

      <span><small>It was, it was. And then in an instant, it wasn't.</small><br>Pues sí, pues sí. Y luego, en un instante, se paró.</span>
      <span><small>- ¿Y por qué Jim no está mojado? - Yo… corrí más.</small><br>Why isn't Jim wet? I...outran it.</span>
      <span><small>No creo que haya llovido. Si no, me dolería la cadera.</small><br>I don't think it rained. My hip would be hurting.</span>


    </center>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: You can try making a list of strings like `['dolor', 'ut']`, and run a loop through this list and process each element with your `hilliter` function

Comment: Welcome to CR! A bit more information and context seems necessary. For example, is this on your own page or on someone else's page (e.g. a userscript)? This strategy destroys all event listeners in the `innerHTML`. What do you mean by group/listing the words? It's better to put your code in the question itself as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) rather than a fiddle, which can change or go down over time. Many folks don't click through to external links just to do a review. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've added in a runnable snippet and some more context on what I'm trying to achieve here. It's my own code, just looking to have it locally rather than on a website. Trying to find a way to highlight multiple words without having to go through the html and highlight each one manually, I've managed to break something though! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var repl = '<span class="sketch-highlight">' + word + '</span>';
```

This line can be made a bit cleaner looking by using template literals:

```
var repl = `<span class="sketch-highlight">${word}</span>`;
```

---

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 0px white;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.825;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
}
```

The CSS rule applies to `.sketch-highlight` elements too, which I presume is not the desired behavior.

`.sketch-highlight` spans can be excluded with the `:not(…)` pseudo-class:

```
span:not(.sketch-highlight) {
```

But it’s better to make a new class name for the `span`s so you don’t need to use `:not(…)`. Example:

```
<span class='main-text'><small>It was, it was. And then in an instant, it wasn't.</small><br>Pues sí, pues sí. Y luego, en un instante, se paró.</span>
<span class='main-text'><small>- ¿Y por qué Jim no está mojado? - Yo… corrí más.</small><br>Why isn't Jim wet? I...outran it.</span>
<span class='main-text'><small>No creo que haya llovido. Si no, me dolería la cadera.</small><br>I don't think it rained. My hip would be hurting.</span>

.main-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 0px white;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.825;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
}
```

---

Currently the highlights are invisible because of their negative `z-index`s.

```
.sketch-highlight::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
```

The negative `z-index`s place the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements *behind* the outer `span`s that have `background-color`s of white.

In order to get the highlights to be visible, a non-negative `z-index` can be set on `.sketch-highlight`:

```
.sketch-highlight {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0; // creates a new stacking context that prevents its children from going behind it
}
```

Putting `z-index: 0` in `.sketch-highlight` creates a [stacking context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) That prevents `.sketch-highlight`’s child elements (including `::before`s and `::after`s) from going behind the container `span`s.

---

```
left: 0em;
top: 0em;
```

Units such as “em” aren’t necessary when the values are zero, so these declarations can be shortened to:

```
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

---

```
<body id='subs'>

  <center>

    <span><small>It was, it was. And then in an instant, it wasn't.</small><br>Pues sí, pues sí. Y luego, en un instante, se paró.</span>
    <span><small>- ¿Y por qué Jim no está mojado? - Yo… corrí más.</small><br>Why isn't Jim wet? I...outran it.</span>
    <span><small>No creo que haya llovido. Si no, me dolería la cadera.</small><br>I don't think it rained. My hip would be hurting.</span>

  </center>
</body>
```

The `<center>` tag is obsolete in HTML5. Consider using a different tag such as `<div>` and `text-align: center;` in CSS.

---

**Results**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function hiliter(word, element) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b", 'gi'); // g modifier for global and i for case insensitive 
    var repl = `<span class="sketch-highlight">${word}</span>`;
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
  }

  function hiliteWords(words, element) {
    words.forEach(word => {
      hiliter(word, element);
    });
  }

  //hiliter('dolor', document.getElementById('dolor'));
  hiliteWords(['creo', 'think',
    'mojado', 'wet'
  ], document.getElementById('subs'));
});
```

```css
.main-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 0px white;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.825;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.sketch-highlight {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.sketch-highlight::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: darkblue;
  position: absolute;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

.sketch-highlight::after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: darkblue;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Brush+Script&family=Nanum+Pen+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body id='subs'>

    <center>

      <span class='main-text'><small>It was, it was. And then in an instant, it wasn't.</small><br>Pues sí, pues sí. Y luego, en un instante, se paró.</span>
      <span class='main-text'><small>- ¿Y por qué Jim no está mojado? - Yo… corrí más.</small><br>Why isn't Jim wet? I...outran it.</span>
      <span class='main-text'><small>No creo que haya llovido. Si no, me dolería la cadera.</small><br>I don't think it rained. My hip would be hurting.</span>

    </center>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```